# Cmder: Keep the bash command line at the bottom

Tags: bash, git-bash, cmder

Any idea how to keep git bash command line at the bottom?
For cmd the solution is here

https://conemu.github.io/en/PromptAtTheBottom.html

Comment: OK, I’m confused. Why are you asking about cmder and linking to a page about ConEmu?

Comment: Because cmder is build on ConEmu

Comment: So,  did my answer work?

Comment: PS1="\[\e9999E\][\d | \T -> \w ...\$?]\n#"   the result is  999E[Tue Mar 05 | 10:28:18 -> /d/Software/cmder ...0]

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have cmder or ConEmu, so I can’t test this,
but the ConEmu answer that you linked to
translates into POSIX shell lingo as this:
add `\[\e9999E\]` to the beginning of your `PS1` string.